# Exported Excel from ASP.NET Core MVC app is corrupted

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core-mvc

I need a expert opinion to resolve a wired issue. I tried many alternatives but went vein.

**The context:** I want to write a utility as an ASP.NET Core MVC web application which will export some data from a database to an Excel workbook using various sheets.

**The problem statement:** the application is exporting the Excel workbook. But once user is clicking the downloaded file to open. Error message is showing the file is corrupt. Though the file contains some data on it.

The client code:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btnDataExport', function () {
        var zId = $("#deZone").val();
        var fId = $("#deFactory").val();
        var mId = $('#deMarket').val();
        var selectedCheckboxes = $('input.chk:checked');
        var selectedIds = [];
        selectedCheckboxes.each(function () {
            selectedIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        var zoneIdsStr = zId.join(',');
        var marketIdsStr = mId.join(',');
        var factoryIdsStr = fId.join(',');
        $.ajax({

            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/DataExport/DataExport',
            data: {
                entities: selectedIds,
                zoneIds: zoneIdsStr,
                marketIds: marketIdsStr,
                factoryIds: factoryIdsStr
               
            },
           
            success: function (data) {
                
                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
                
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = 'Export.xlsx';
                link.click();
                
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while loading the page");
            }    
        });
    });
```

The server side code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DataExport(List<string> entities, List<int> zoneIds, List<int>marketIds,List<int> factoryIds)
{
    // byte[] fileContents;
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            if (string.Compare(entity, "YearlyZoneKPIs", false) == 0)
            {
                var yearlyZoneKPIs = _dataexportservice.GetYearlyZoneKpis(zoneIds, marketIds);
                ExcelWorksheet worksheetyearlyZoneKPIs = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("YearlyZoneKPIs");
                DataExportExcelFactory.CreateExcelForYearlyZoneKPIs(ref worksheetyearlyZoneKPIs, yearlyZoneKPIs);
             }
         }
    }

    using (MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        package.SaveAs(mstream);
        return File(mstream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "ExportedData.xlsx");
    }
}
```

Here `DataExportExcelFactory.CreateExcelForYearlyZoneKPIs` is a static method to populate a excel by ref with the data passed in second param, here yearlyZoneKPIs.

Comment: What library are you using for generating the Excel sheet? Why do you think the JavaScript code is relevant here? (I am assuming you have debugged it, so you know if the data is being uploaded as expected)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using ClosedXML v 0.95.4.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `using` block you have placed around the `MemoryStream` will dispose of the stream before it's used in the `File()` result, because it is being returned outside of the `using` block's scope. make sure memory stream remains open and available until after the file has been fully written to the response.

Here is the code which will handle the disposal of the MemoryStream after the file has been written to the response, so you do not need to manually dispose of it.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DataExport(List<string> entities, List<int> zoneIds, List<int> marketIds, List<int> factoryIds)
{
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        // ... (adding worksheets code)

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        package.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0; 

        return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "ExportedData.xlsx", true);
    }
}
```

Apart from this if you're fetching the data using `$.ajax`, jQuery may not handle binary data correctly because it does not know the data type of the response ahead of time. you could try this below approach using the Fetch API with a `responseType` of `blob`, or setting up the proper `xhrFields` if sticking with jQuery

```
fetch('/DataExport/DataExport', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        entities: selectedIds,
        zoneIds: zoneIdsStr,
        marketIds: marketIdsStr,
        factoryIds: factoryIdsStr
    }),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'Export.xlsx';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();    
    a.remove(); 
}).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Comment: Many many thanks. The excel is generating with data. But there is another and final hitch related to param binding . The param values which I am passing in the fetch function to access the DataExport action method, only first value i.e. List<string> entities are mapped properly, the remaining params are showing count 0. If you can put some light on that. It will be really great. I am also trying from my end.